# Class Reference on ilnumerics.net / IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, ilnumerics

IE10 doesn't show the Class Reference at ilnumerics.net properly:

http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/Index.html

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly related to ILNumerics. It rather is a known problem which applies to all sandcastle documentations: http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/workitem/12073

You may circumvent the issue by one of the following methods:

- enable the compatibility mode in IE10 (the tiled little page symbol in the adress bar)
- use Firefox or Chrome instead